# Maven with Android - R.java file generation (Eclipse)

Tags: android, maven-2

I am trying to get working R.java generation to project in gen folder. Actually, the application builds, when using maven build, however eclipse finds error, because it can't resolve R.java file (which actually is being put in /target/generated-sources/r/R.java location after each build). What is the suggested way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The recommended way is to use the **Maven Integration for Android Development Tools** and the Maven Android Plugin provides instructions. From the [Eclipse Integration](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/EclipseIntegration) page:

> ### Introduction
>
> Android's official development effort
>   provides solid support for Eclipse
>   integration, and we'd like to make
>   sure maven-android-plugin helps bridge
>   Maven, Android, and Eclipse. This page
>   will help us collect information on
>   what works and doesn't work
>
> #### The solution
>
> To make maven-android-plugin work well
>   in Eclipse with ADT, this is what you
>   need:
>
> 1. Go to the [M2Eclipse Android Integration project page](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/m2eclipse-android-integration/) and
>      install the tools listed under
>      Requirements.
> 2. Of course, set up update-site url and install the M2Eclipse Android
>      Integration plugin in Eclipse.  * Get
>      version 0.2.2 or later. It should be
>      under the category 'Maven Integration
>      for Android Development Tools'.
> 3. In Eclipse, to bring in your Maven Android projects, choose File ->
>      Import... -> Maven -> Existing Maven
>      Projects.

So jump to the [M2Eclipse Android Integration project page](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/m2eclipse-android-integration/) and then to the [Getting Started](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/m2eclipse-android-integration/wiki/GettingStarted) guide for very detailed instructions.

With the right tooling, the directory of the generated code should be added automatically as source directory under Eclipse.

Comment: I'll check the solution out in couple of days, because at first I'm proceeding with work on base project, without worrying about mavenizing it.

Comment: Now I see I got crazy with mixing maven with android. For further generations: just add the "generated-sources/r" to sources in Eclipse.

Comment: Unfortunately the ADT doesn't include your Maven dependencies in APK files it builds, so you may need support from the M2Eclipse Android Integration plug-in.

Comment: I have all the required plugins.  The only R file I can find is in target/generated-sources/r/... and it is empty.  Where's the real thing?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and just found the solution.

Reason was that I started with a new workspace in which I imported my mavenized android projects. Since it was a new workspace, it didn't contain the **SDK location in the preferences**.

Once that was setup, all was well.

Answer (score 0):

Also remember that you must have the following code in your eclipse .project file:

```
<name>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder</name>
    <arguments>
    </arguments>
</buildCommand>
<buildCommand>
    <name>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder</name>
    <arguments>
    </arguments>
</buildCommand>
```

Answer (score -4):

Other option is disable maven dependency, and add external library in your android project

- commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
- spring-android-rest-template-1.0.0.M2.jar
- jackson-core-asl-1.7.2.jar
- jackson-mapper-asl-1.7.2.jar

and remove pom.xml,then build project, and run as > Android Application

Comment: So disable maven basically. Very cute.